# Sabre Hotel Availability API - ‡NO LISTING THIS CTY

Tags: sabre

All requests I make to the Hotel Availability API are met with ‡NO LISTING THIS CTY error responses.  I'm not sure what the issue could be as I'm near certain my credentials are correct the requests I'm using are directly from Sabre's given examples.  I've placed an example request and response below;

Request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www. w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId>Us</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To> 
        <eb:PartyId>SabreAPI</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>OurPCC</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>ourConvID</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">OurToken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.3.0">
      <AvailRequestSegment>
        <GuestCounts Count="1"/>
        <HotelSearchCriteria>
          <Criterion>
            <Address>
              <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
            <HotelRef HotelCityCode="DFW"/>
          </Criterion>
        </HotelSearchCriteria>
        <TimeSpan End="04-24" Start="04-22"/>
      </AvailRequestSegment>
    </OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">SabreAPI</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Us</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>OurPCC</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>OurConvID</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRS</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>1676193648756670150</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2018-03-27T18:01:17</eb:Timestamp>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">OurToken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <OTA_HotelAvailRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://         services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-03-27T13:01:17-05:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>&#135;NO LISTING THIS CTY</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</OTA_HotelAvailRS>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I contacted Sabre web services support and this seems to be a problem within Sabre's system itself.  It is being taken care of by Sabre.